# TryGet with out in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, is it possible to achieve something like the TryGet pattern using [out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier) that is popular in C#?

Example:

```cs
if(TryGetFoo(out Foo foo)
{
    Debug.Log("Got the foo, and here is it's bar: " + foo.bar);
}
else {
    Debug.Log("Can't get the foo!)";
}
```

---

The point is that the function returns a bool, whereas the out returns the value/object. Saves having to create and check a separate variable.

---

In TypeScript, I currently would do this:

```
const foo = getFoo();

if(foo)
{
    console.log("Got the foo, and here is it's bar: " + foo.bar);
}
else {
    console.log("Can't get the foo!");
}
```

Comment: You can't do it _in JavaScript_, so no. Assignment is an expression in JavaScript, `if (foo = getFoo())` is valid syntax, but TypeScript won't be happy if `foo` isn't declared somewhere.

Comment: I think you can pass the reference and the function populate the ref, Something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEAuGYCuAbDMA+q0C2ARgKYBOMAvDAIwAMAUAwJZhTlwCGwJMAkgDFEAJRJwYAbwYwZ8RAH4U6YuQYBfJnDRhgUZuBgAVMgE8A4iShCQACjJiUgkWICUKe+OYQYogI5pmewATAB4nEFE4AD5JaVlmcRsEEBcYDwA6ZKo5ECZZNMs0MjAYAEJS5PUmAHpqmABRMCCYEHEtHT1wJlBIWA9Ha0jsiQ0WRONzS2s7VxcpfJ6IEAwSdIwQAHMZuEzEF3USDAgSedlF5dX1rYAiaxggkBIIMAByWBIADy8oa-21IA)?

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is "just" typing of JavaScript.

JavaScript doesn't (yet?) support this kind of feature.